# Program of cash machine

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I return my code at the start?

I need to return this code back to the statement `odpoved=input("vlozit/status/vybrat/koniec: ")` because I want repeating my program again and again, until a user will choose the choice `"koniec"` (then this program will finish).

**I'm a beginner.**

```
value=10
def koniec():
    print("dovidenia")

def status():
    print("Aktuálny zostatok na účte je {} EUR.".format(value))

def vybr():
    vyber=input("Aktuálny zostatok na účte je {} EUR. Zadaj hodnotu, ktorú chceš vybrať: ".format(value))
    vyber2=float(vyber)
    if vyber2 > value:
        print("Váš výber je o {} EUR väčší ako Váš aktuálny zostatok.".format(vyber2-value))
    elif vyber2 <= value:
        print("Schválene...", "\n", "Vyberte si peniaze.", "\n", "Noví zostatok na Vašom účte je {} EUR.".format(value-vyber2))

def vlz():
    vloz=input("Zadaj hodnotu, ktorú chceš vložiť: ")
    vloz=float(vloz)
    print("Nový zostatok na účte je {} EUR.".format(value+vloz))



odpoved=input("vlozit/status/vybrat/koniec: ")
while odpoved == "koniec":
    koniec()
else:
    while odpoved == "status":
        status()
        break
        zisti=input("vlozit/vybrat")


    while odpoved == "vybrat":
        vybr()
        break

    while odpoved == "vlozit":
        vlz()
        break
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Most people here don't understand your language. It would be useful to translate at least some important words from your code (e.g. the names of your functions and the words used in the `input()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be a bit confused about the proper use of conditionals (`if`/`elif`/`else`) and loops...

Here you basically want an infinite `while` loop, in which you ask the user what he wants to do, and use conditionals to dispatch to the proper action (one of them being to exit the loop):

```
while True:
    thing_to_do = input("what should I do ?")
    if thing_to_do = "exit":
        break
    elif thing_to_do == "dothis"
        dothis()
    elif thing_to_do == "dothat":
        dothat()
    else:
        print("sorry, I don't know how to do '{}'".format(thing_to_do))
```

Comment: Now, I know... Thank you so much.

Comment: @AuthorCliment glad I could help - and feel free to accept and/or upvote the answer if it solved your problem.